# Detect change in text file using C++ i without Infinite Loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, file-io

I am reading a text file using C++. I am using the first line to indicate if the file has changed or not. For example, text file will look like :

```
  0
  9
```

After the text file has been changed I am flipping the first line. So, the new text file will look like:

```
  1
  5
```

C++ code will perform its functions after reading the new input from the text file. Currently, I am using infinite loop to detect changes in the text file. Is there any alternative implementation of detecting changes in the text file using C++? This is my solution so far:

```
   do{
      std::ifstream reader;
      reader.open(READFILE);
      if (!reader){
       printf("Error opening the reader file!!");
       exit(1);
     }
     reader >> status >> variable;

     if(status != reader_file_status){
       reader_file_status = status;
       return true
     }
  } while(true);
```

Comment: Many operating system allow to install something like the [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) file watching mechanism. You'll still have an endless loop, but it will be sitting on a blocking call, until you get notified that something has changed. Other than that your question is highly dependent on your actual operating system and **too broad** to give you really good advice. That you're using c++ for implementation is an almost irrelevant detail, the c++ standard doesn't support such (even not the experimental c++17 `std::filesystem`) mechanism at all.

Comment: Does such an external change modify the file time? Its size? (And are you sure your code is thread safe?)

Comment: Most operating systems have functionality to detect file changes. For example FindFirstChangeNotification  on windows.

Comment: I am running MiniSAT with some modifications. I think it uses threads to speed up the search process. I think it might be changing the time.

Comment: @mousecoder _"I am running MiniSAT ..."_ is that some kind of linux clone? Never heard about that OS.

Comment: @TheDude: Its the SAT solver to find solutions to satisfiability formulae. Is it possible give a simple implementation of C++ interacting with inotify? Also, will I be able to achieve any efficiency if I don't use infinite loop from within the C++ code?

Comment: @mousecoder _inotify_ supports a C-API thus this just integrates seamlessly with your c++ code, there's plenty of examples in the documentation, and all over the interwebz. Just google for it. _"Also, will I be able to achieve any efficiency ..."_ Sure, as I mentioned, you'll be sitting at a blocking call.

Answer (score 1):

filesystem change events are platform specific, so you'll need different solutions for different platforms.

- osx: file system events api [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html)
- freebsd/osx: kqueue [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html)
- linux: inotify [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)
- windows: windows api [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx)

It seems some cross platform wrappers are around. A quick googling revealed:

- https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch (gpl3, osx/freebsd/linux/windows/solaris)
- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html (lgpl, osx/freebsd/windows)